# How to prove this number theoretic question in CAGD?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Suppose that $f,g,d$ are real coefficient polynomial such that $(f,d)=(g,d)=1\ in \ R[x]$,what's more,$d(x)>0 ,\forall x\in R$ .

Prove that $f(t)^3+g(t)^3=d(t)^3,\forall t\in R$ is not possible unless they are all constant.

This comes from the question that the algebraic curve $x^3+y^3-1=0$ can't be represented as a rational bezier curve,my teacher gives a wrong proof,and i can't prove it myself.Thank anybody who is thinking about this question.

Comment: $f(t)^3+g(t)^3=d(t)^3$ is impossible even over $\mathbb C$. See for instance https://micromath.wordpress.com/2008/05/24/fermats-last-theorem-for-polynomials/

Comment: Thank you very much for this hint,i haven't think of that i should extent this to C[x].I was trying to prove this based on $(f(t)+g(t))(f(t)^2+g(t)^2-f(t)g(t))=d(t)^3$.